# How to get the wordpress post in Java Rest API?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I want to fetch the WordPress post/blog of my site using some kind of REST API. I want to understand to fetch the html, for example, I tried but its not great for Images. `https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/ajayramezh.wordpress.com/posts/6` 
I want to render that post in my another website, for that how to get the blog so that it is ready to render instantly. At present I am thinking iframe to get the render.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
// body content from wordpress rest api. At present it works fine for simple data, for images it's giving wordpress specific tags which doesn't understand my site.

</body>
</html>
```

[High Level Diagram-draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFw4e.png)

Comment: This might help, I am using WPeMatico plugin, it enables administrators to create posts automatically from RSS/Atom feeds with multiples filters.

Comment: The consumer of the website is not a wordpress site, it is a simplie MVC website. This WPeMatico helps if the consumer is wordpress website, but that is not my cast.